# Doubt in electricity chapter

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I understand that when calculating the total resistance in a balanced wheatstone bridge, the middle resistor's resistance is ignored. But what happens when I include it's value and calculate the total resistance?

Comment: If you do that, your answer becomes incorrect, as in a balanced Wheatstone Bridge the potential difference across the "middle" resistor is $0$ and hence no current flows through it.

Comment: If the bridge is balanced, the total resistance is the same with or without the middle resistor.